# Unshuffled string is different from original string after shuffling and unshuffling

Tags: c, arrays, shuffle

I'm actually implementing a shuffling function with an un-shuffling function. I'm using the Fisher-Yates algorithm with pseudo random number generator with a fixed seed. The unshuffled string doesn't look like the initial string, however.

I've checked if my random array is the same in the shuffling function and the un-shuffling function. The unshuffling function is the same as the shuffling function but in reverse.

Here is my shuffling function :

```
void shuffle(char * phrase) 
    {
        int size_phrase = strlen(phrase);
        srand(seed);
        int * rdm_array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size_phrase);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < size_phrase; i++)
        {
            rdm_array[i] = rand()%size_phrase;
            //printf("%d", rdm_array[i]);
        }
        //begin shuffle here
        int j;
        int k = 0;
        for(j = size_phrase -1 ; j > 0 ; j-- , k++)
        {
            int rdm_nb = rdm_array[k];
            char temp = phrase[j];
            phrase[j] = phrase[rdm_nb];
            phrase[rdm_nb] = temp;
        }
        free(rdm_array);
    }
```

And here is my unshuffling function :

```
 void unshuffle(char * phrase)
{
    int size_phrase = strlen(phrase);
    srand(seed);
    int * rdm_array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size_phrase);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size_phrase; i++)
    {
        rdm_array[i] = rand()%size_phrase; 
        //printf("%i", rdm_array[i]);
    }
    //On commence le mélange ici
    int j;
    int k = size_phrase-1;
    for(j = 0 ; j < size_phrase ; j++ , k--)
    {
        int rdm_nb = rdm_array[k];
        char temp = phrase[j];
        phrase[j] = phrase[rdm_nb];
        phrase[rdm_nb] = temp;  
    }
    free(rdm_array);
}
```

And here is my Output :

[image: My Output]

It looks like it's missing one loop or something like that.

Comment: Hm. I think you should work hard to reduce the problem to its bar minimum. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `rand()%size_phrase` can you show your `srand()`? You can't unshuffle a random shuffle.... you can sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `printf` to show what gets exchanged in both `shuffle` and `unshuffle` like this

```
        /* after this line */
        int rdm_nb = rdm_array[k];
        /* insert debug output */
        printf("%d <-> %d\n", j, rdm_nb);
```

You will see that in function `shuffle` variable `j` counts from `size_phrase -1` to `1` while in `unshuffle` it counts from `0` to `size_phrase -1`.

Probably you should change the `for` loop in `shuffle` to

```
    for(j = size_phrase -1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- , k++)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll keep in mind that write a debug output is very usefull when I got a problem ! Thank you